# Get Multilingual Data from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, udp

I am receiving ByteBuffers in an UDP Java application.

Now the data in this ByteBuffer can be any string in any language or any special chars separated by **zero**.

I use following code to get Strings from it.

```
public String getString() {
byte[] remainingBytes = new byte[this.byteBuffer.remaining()];
this.byteBuffer.slice().get(remainingBytes);
String dataString = new String(remainingBytes);
int stringEnd = dataString.indexOf(0);

if(stringEnd == -1) {
    return null;
} else {
    dataString = dataString.substring(0, stringEnd);
    this.byteBuffer.position(this.byteBuffer.position() + dataString.getBytes().length + 1);

    return dataString;
}
}
```

These strings are stored in  MySQL DB with everything set as **UTF8**.

IF i run application in Windows then special chars like ®  are displayed but chinese are not.

On adding VM argument **-Dfile.encoding=UTF8** chinese are displayed but chars like ® are shown as ?? etc.

Please Help.

Edit:

Input Strings in UDP packet are **variable-length byte field, encoded in UTF-8, terminated by 0x00**

For JDBC also i use **useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String dataString = new String(remainingBytes);` is wrong. You should almost never do that. You should find out what encoding was used to put the bytes into the UDP packet, and use the same encoding on that line:

```
String dataString = new String(remainingBytes, encoding); // e.g. "UTF-8"
```

Edit: based on your updated question, `encoding` should be `"UTF-8"`

Comment: Is it necessary even while using -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 as VM argument?

Comment: Yes. Don't use that VM argument, it's not relevant

Comment: on using **new String(remainingBytes,"UTF-8");**  and **dataString.getBytes("UTF-8")**  Chinese char are displayed properly.
But ® is not displayed !!

Comment: Where is this incorrect display? You have to get the encoding correct from end-to-end, so there could still be bugs in your JDBC code, or your display output. Try reading http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I dont think there is bug in JDBC code because the data is also getting messed up when it encounters 
® . Which i check by printing to console . AND dataString.indexOf(0) also return wrong values the moment ® is encountered.

Comment: Can it have any relation to negative values because ®  is shown as 62 -82 in byte fields?

Comment: According to http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder, those bytes do not correspond to ® in UTF-8, so you are receiving mangled data.

Comment: Using default encoding (windows-1252) it is getting displayed .But i want to use UTF8 for chinese support also. On debugging i have found that **dataString.getBytes().length** returns different values in special chars when using different encodings !!

Comment: Difference in positions is 2  on using "UTF 8 and without"

Comment: Maybe the data in that packet was not encoded in UTF8 . Thanks a lot.
How should i handle packets that were not encoded in UTF8

Comment: Don't call `getBytes()` on a `String` either - it's platform-dependent. Always specify an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but dataString contains only data till this zero, because stringEnd shows on first zero postion but not behind.

dataString = dataString.substring(0, stringEnd+1);

or

char specChar = dataString.substring(stringEnd, stringEnd+1); and it should return only special character, but as I said in the biggining, not sure...

Comment: it works perfectly for English data. I call getString() multiple times to get further data.